# Show dialog while writing and do not block UI

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, textwatcher

I am trying to show a dialog with two buttons when a i start typing with my soft keyboard. Is it possible to avoid the dialog block the UI, so i can continue writing with the dialog still present?

I was also wondering how to detect a space bar keystroke with TextWatcher.

My current progress is:

I set a addTextChangedListener to my edittext and when i start typing the dialog pops up, but cannot keep on writing.

```
private TextWatcher textwatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        builder.setMessage("What do you want to add?")
                .setPositiveButton("Add #",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Add @",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

};
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to show a Dialog?

Dialog in an intrusive mechanism which requires user action. The non-intrusive way is to use [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Comment: Yes but i do not want to just show a message, i need to have a couple of buttons to make an action

Comment: Then it wont work. You can only have one at active at a time. How about using ActionBar then.

Comment: I think i dont get you, what do you mean using action bar? what i really need is that when i start writing i need some kind of popup with a button or something. Then when clicking the button, for example, making the current word bold

Comment: You cant do that with Dialog for sure. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html